# Origami fold effect for UIView and NavigationController Bar

Tags: animation, uiview, catransform3d, origami

I need to implement the functionality that this library provides: [XYOrigami](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYOrigami). The main issue, is I must implement it to fold on the center view when the left view is revealed rather fold the side views. Unfortunately, this has become quite a task (and I'm currently looking at manipulating the library below to do so). The left tray should be just a tray with a width of 100 to 200. When it comes out, the center view should have a cringle origami effect and fold until the tray is hidden again. Is anyone aware of a library that does this or a way to accomplish this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get the sample code in  [mpospese / EnterTheMatrix](https://github.com/mpospese/EnterTheMatrix)
  repository.

Just have a look at the second last tab,"The Fold Animation" & then click view. 
I think this view can be taken as the center view for your case & `XYOrigami` as the side menu.

You many need to tweak the `EnterTheMatrix` to fold-unfold horizontally unlikely as it fold-unfold vertically by default.

I hope you can make a new custom component hybridized from the above two Custom controls.

Happy Coding.

Hope that Helps.